# Need help on implementing jquery parameters of responsive radial menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to implement radial responsive menu [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a1khan/evLwp1jf/4/)
unable to pass additional parameters like menu position(bottom right etc) form this page [Prameters](http://www.oswego.edu/~arahmadi/radial-menu/)

menu is not working with bottom-right parameter

```
$('#radial-menu').radialResponsiveMenu({
     'circleRadius': 70,
     'togglePosition': bottom-right
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 9 options for this plugin that you can use.

Please Check :

https://github.com/agylardi/radial-responsive-menu

Use `togglePosition` option to set position for menu:

I have made example check [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/evLwp1jf/5/)

Comment: as soon as i add 'togglePosition': bottom-right as given in the above link the menu does not work , http://jsfiddle.net/a1khan/evLwp1jf/4/

Comment: thanks vijay changed ur fiddle css with this position:fixed;
 bottom: 10px;
 right: 10px;  and not the bottom-left parameter is working

Comment: Now You can customize as per your requirements

Comment: can i have only one level menu with five links (list items) and no sub-menu ul's or list items from here [link](http://www.oswego.edu/~arahmadi/radial-menu/)

Comment: can u limit the links to show the outer five links and not the inner three in ur fiddle

Comment: Just remove those links

Comment: can u make the menu go to normal state after clicking on  any of the list item links in your fiddle

Answer (score 0):

I think the demo page isn't generating usable javascript - you're likely to get an undefined variable error with what you have, as it will be trying to assign the value of the variable `bottom` minus the value of the variable `right`, both of which (probably) don't exist.  Try wrapping it in quotes:

```
$('#radial-menu').radialResponsiveMenu({
     'circleRadius': 70,
     'togglePosition': 'bottom-right'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your Code to:

```
$('#radial-menu').radialResponsiveMenu({
     'circleRadius': 70,
     'togglePosition': 'bottom-right'
});
```

In your CSS add `position:absolute; bottom:10px; right:10px;` to #radial menu.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
$('#radial-menu').radialResponsiveMenu({
          'togglePosition': $('.positioned').css({ 'top': '', 'right':'10px', 'bottom':'10px', 'left':'' });
});
```

and in css define a class like this: `.positioned{position:absolute;}`

in html : `<nav id="radial-menu" class="positioned">`

thats it.

Comment: how can i make the links fade back after click on the list items (li) currently have to click the menu button is on open/close toggle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/a1khan/evLwp1jf/4/)